# Magento2 cron function not running:

Tags: magento2, magento-cron

I have created a custom module for cron but it's not running at all:

**crontab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="arunendra_notification">
        <job name="arunendra_sendfcm" instance="Arunendra\Notification\Cron\Sendfcm" method="execute">
            <schedule>0/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>   
        <job name="arunendra_stock" instance="Arunendra\Notification\Cron\Stocknotification" method="execute">
            <schedule>0/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>  
    </group>
</config>
```

**cron_groups.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Arunendra_Notification:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="arunendra_notification">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>60</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

**Cron function :**

```
<?php

namespace Arunendra\Notification\Cron;
use Exception;
use \Magento\ProductAlert\Model\ProductSalability;
class Stocknotification
{
   
    protected $logger; 
    protected $_notiHelper;
    protected $_fcmFactory;  
    protected $connection;
    protected $resource;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $productSalability;
    protected $customerRepository;
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,   
        \Arunendra\Notification\Helper\Data $notiHelper,   
        \Arunendra\Notification\Model\FcmFactory $fcmFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductSalability $productSalability = null
    ) {
        $this->logger       = $logger;
        $this->_notiHelper  = $notiHelper;        
        $this->_fcmFactory  = $fcmFactory;     
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $this->resource = $resource;  
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $this->productSalability = $productSalability ?: $objectManager->get(ProductSalability::class);
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function execute()
    {
      $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/stockcron.log');
      $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
      $logger->addWriter($writer);
        try {
           $website = $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
           $connection = $resource->getConnection();
           $tableName = $resource->getTableName("product_alert_stock");          
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE fcm_status is null";
           $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
           foreach ($result as $alert) {
                $poductId   = $alert['product_id'];
                $websiteId  = $alert['website_id'];
                $customerId = $alert['customer_id'];
                $customer   = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
                $product    = $this->productRepository->getById($poductId,false,$websiteId);
                $product->setCustomerGroupId($customer->getGroupId());
                if ($this->productSalability->isSalable($product, $website)) {
                     $data = [
                        "message" =>$product->getName().' back in stock',
                      "image" => $product->getThumbnail(),
                        "title" =>'Products back in stock',     
                        "type" => 1,
                        "id" => ""
                    ];                  
                    $device_token = $this->getFcmByCustId($customerId);  
                  if(!empty($device_token)){
                    $logger->info('Array Log'.print_r($device_token, true)); // Array Log
                    $this->_notiHelper->sendNotification($device_token,$data);   
                    $id = $alert['alert_stock_id'];                   
                    $sql = "update $tableName set fcm_status=1 where id=$id";
                    $connection->query($sql);
                  }                 
                }
           }
          
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
          //  $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
            $logger->info('Array Log'.print_r($e->getMessage(), true)); // Array Log
        }    
        $logger->info('Simple Text Log'); // Simple Text Log
    }
    private function getFcmByCustId($customer_id){
        $model = $this->_fcmFactory->create();
        return $model->load($customer_id, 'customer_id')->getDeviceToken();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure 0/5 * * * * is a valid Cron. Do you mean */5 * * * * to run the cron every 5 minutes ?

Comment: @Taschert you are right, I have fixed that typo

Comment: perfect did it solved the issue ?

Comment: @Now I can see the records in the cron table but my function never executed

Comment: Do you have the cron running on your machine ? Il not you need to run "php bin/magneto cron:run" multiple times for this to work. The first time magento schedule the cron and the next one the are run.

Comment: Yes, I have set up it, is there any way to run cron function like controller function to check  it?

Comment: I'm not sure, you could create a CLI to run it. Or you can call the execute method from a controller if you inject your class in the constructor.